# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,672,3) into shape (224,672)

Tags: keras, python-3.x

```
def Model_Resnet(train_data,  sol):

    IMG_SIZE = [224, 224, 3]

    train_data = np.array(train_data)

    Feat1 = np.zeros((train_data.shape[0], IMG_SIZE[0], IMG_SIZE[1] * IMG_SIZE[2]))

    for i in range(train_data.shape[0]):
        Feat1[i, :] = cv.resize(train_data[i], (IMG_SIZE[1] * IMG_SIZE[2],IMG_SIZE[0]))

    train_data = Feat1.reshape(Feat1.shape[0], IMG_SIZE[0], IMG_SIZE[1], IMG_SIZE[2])

    base_model = Sequential()
    base_model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='max'))
    base_model.add(Dense(units=int(sol[0]), activation='sigmoid'))
    base_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',epoches = sol[1],  metrics=['acc'])
    try:
        base_model.fit(train_data)
        pred = np.round(base_model.predict(train_data)).astype('int')
    except:
         pred = np.round(base_model.predict(train_data)).astype('int')
    return pred.astype('int')
```

Comment: Hello @gvijayakiran, welcome to the site. Please, provide information about what line the problem happens, and the full backtrace, so that the community can understand the cause of the problem.